# Kafka and global exception handlers

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, nestjs

I am using kafka in nestjs. The happy path works as expected. For the unhappy path, I decided to throw an Error.

The overall goal is to log the Error, complete processing the event and continue to the next message.

```
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { Controller } from "@nestjs/common"

@Controller()
export class EventController {
  @MessagePattern('test_service')
  async get(event: any) {

    if (event.test) {
      console.log('ok')
      return
    }

    console.log('not ok')
    throw new Error('Test')
  }
}
```

In other projects, we throw Errors in the business logic and let the errors bubble to the global exception handler, and then return responses using HTTP or whatever.

I have implemented a global exception handler in nestjs

```
import { BadRequestError } from "../../domain/errors/bad-request.error"
import { RpcExceptionFilter } from "@nestjs/common/interfaces"
import { Catch, ArgumentsHost, Inject } from "@nestjs/common"
import { LoggingService } from "../services/logging.service"
import { RpcException } from "@nestjs/microservices"
import { Observable, EMPTY } from "rxjs"

@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionFilter implements RpcExceptionFilter {
  constructor(@Inject('LoggingService') private readonly logging: LoggingService) { }

  catch(exception: RpcException, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
    const data = host.switchToRpc().getData()
    this.handleException(data, exception)

    return EMPTY
  }

  private handleException(data: any, error: unknown): void {
    switch (true) {
      case (error instanceof BadRequestError):
        this.logging.error('BadRequestError', error, { data })
        break
      default:
        this.logging.error('UnexpectedError', error, { data })
        break
    }
  }
}
```

And in my module definition I define it in the providers

```
{
  provide: APP_FILTER,
  useClass: GlobalExceptionFilter,
  scope: Scope.REQUEST
}
```

By returning an empty observable, I thought that caught exceptions would be 'lost' after this point and so the kafka consumer will complete the consumption of the message.

However, it seems that *any* thrown exception simply makes the kafka consumer retry and then restart. I have tried different [configuration options from the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/kafka#options) but regardless of what I try, I cannot get the global exception handler to work as I expect.

The simple work around is to simply inject an instance of the logging class into the consumer and instead of throwing, log. Still, it would be nice if the project can follow the implementations of our other HTTP projects.

Is it possible to use a global exception handler and kafka to log errors but complete the processing of the event?